# Replace NA value in one column and row based on value in a different column and row amongst groups but retain values that are not NA in the group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am trying to replace the NA value in one row and column with a value in the same column but based on the conditional value in another column. However, I also need to maintain the 567 value for column Value_1. I don't think my code would be helpful in this instance. The data looks like:

```
Group_Name     Value_1     Status
    A            NA          NA
    A           12345      Active
    A           567          NA
```

The end result should be something like:

```
Group_Name       Value_1       Status
    A             12345          NA
    A             12345          Active
    A              567           NA
```

Any solution with tidyverse, data.table, or base R would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% mutate(Value_1 = Value_1[Status %in% 'Active'], .by = Group_Name)`

Comment: @akrun I slightly misstated the problem. I also need to retain Value_1 despite the status given it is already present. Is there an additional conditional statement required?